# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Wins' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, while-loop

I've got the objects and I've called them properly but I keep getting these errors. Anyone know why? It says 'Wins' from the player object is not defined but it clearly is.

This is what it shows when I call `startGame();` in the console.

> script.js:56 undefined has NaN left.
>   script.js:58 Almighty Grant has NaN left.

```js
var playerName = prompt('Name your character');

var player = {
  Name: playerName,
  Health: 40,
  HealsLeft: 2,
  Wins: 0,
  attackDamage: function(num) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  },
  healsRandom: function(num) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
  }
};

console.log(player.healsRandom());
```

Comment: To answer your specific question: The player object you want is a local variable to `startGame()` so to `startCombat()` it isn't defined. You have 2 different player variables, it checks for the Wins property on your global player variable which doesn't have a Wins property

Comment: You can post that code here if you want help with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the answer of @Jeff Matthews, even if you've called `startCombat()` after you created the player. It still won't work, why?

The problem lies on your `startCombat` function.

```
function startCombat() {
  while (player.Wins < 5 && player.Health > 0) {
    attackOrQuit = prompt('Do you want to attack, heal or quit?');
    if (attackOrQuit === "heal") {
      player.Health +=  player.healsRandom;
      this.HealsLeft--;
      console.log(player.Name + " has healed and has " + player.Health + " health.")
    } else if (attackOrQuit === "quit") {
      break;
    }

    ...
```

You are using the `player` variable which turns out, is not initialized! You don't believe me? Here :D

In `startCombat`, *JavaScript* tried to find the name `player`, which it finds in the global scope. Yes, here:

```
var i = 0;
var playerName;
var attackOrQuit;
var player; // <-- here
```

**But I've initialized it in the `startGame` function?!**

Yes you've did, but there's just a bit of something wrong.

Inside `startGame`, you've done well in initializing `player`, but just one thing, you've used `var`, meaning, you're creating a new *variable* named `player` under the **scope** of `startGame` function.

So that `player` variable you've created will just be available on `startGame`'s scope.

One solution is to omit the `var`.

```
player = {
  Name: playerName,
  Health: 40,
  HealsLeft: 2,
  Wins: 0,
  attackDamage: function (){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    },
  healsRandom:  function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
  }
};
```

When you omit the `var`, Instead of creating a new variable, *JavaScript* will find that variable, if it finds none, it will create a new **global scope** variable, otherwise, it will modify that variable that it found.

You also have other variables you are using on another *function* which are not available in the global scope. Like the `opponent` variable, it is just a local variable inside `startCombat`. (yes, other functions don't know them!)

Simple explanation of what is happening:

```
var i = 0;

function start() {
    var i = 1; // <-- creates a new variable `i` in its own scope
    startAgain();
}

function startAgain() {
    console.log(i); // <-- no variable `i` found in its scope, so let's find some in the global scope.
    // looks like it found one; with a value of `0`
}

start();
```

This will output `0`.

Note: I'm not sure of the terms I'm using, that's just how I can express what's happening; any corrections are perfectly fine!

**UPDATE**

Didn't use `var` keyword but *JavaScript* didn't find that variable example:

```
function start() {
    i = 1; // <-- JavaScript tries to find `i`
    // <-- it founds none, well, let's make this a `global scope` variable
    startAgain();
}

function startAgain() {
    console.log(i);
}
```

This will output `1`.

**UPDATE**

Your computation is wrong, you're adding a `function` pointer to the `Health`.

Here:

```
player.Health +=  player.healsRandom;
```

It should be:

```
player.Health +=  player.healsRandom();
```

Do the same for `player.attackDamage` and `opponent.attackDamage`

Comment: so I made the var player and var opponent within startCombat(). but it still produces this error: Batman has NaN left. Almighty Grant has NaN left. https://repl.it/repls/UnsungNaiveAntipodesgreenparakeet

Comment: do this solution: remove both `var` keyword inside `startGame` when you initialize `player` and `opponent`, that should work.

Comment: okay, removed the var keywords from both opponent and player (both of which are now in the startCombat function, and its still giving me the same error.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I just learned about objects and methods today so I completed forgot about the parenthesis. THANK YOU THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You are calling startCombat() before you define your player{}.